# MomentJS invalid date

Tags: reactjs, npm, momentjs

I'm trying to convert a date string like 'DD-MM-YYYY', to 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
Unfortunately I'm getting a invalid date.

```
  var startDate = $('.startDate').val();
  var endDate = $('.endDate').val();

  var newstartDate = moment(startDate).format( "YYYY-MM-DD");
  endDate = moment(endDate, "YYYY-MM-DD");

  console.log('startDate:',startDate)
  console.log('newstartDate:',newstartDate)
  console.log('endDate:',endDate)
```

[image]

How could I get the output as: 2018-09-14 . / 2018-08-14 ?

Comment: Not related to your question, but, it seems to me that you are using react and jQuery at the same time. This is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var startDate = "22-12-2009";
  var endDate = "01-02-2009";

  var newstartDate = moment(startDate,'DD-MM-YYYY').format( "YYYY-MM-DD");
  endDate = moment(endDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY');

  console.log('startDate:',startDate)
  console.log('newstartDate:',newstartDate)
  console.log('endDate:',endDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Specify the input date format when parsing with moment `moment(startDate,'DD-MM-YYYY').format( "YYYY-MM-DD");`

Comment: Thanks. I feel stupid now for forgetting the specification of the input date. :)